# How to Use 'DATEADD' function in Laravel join?

Tags: php, sql, join, laravel-4, laravel-query-builder

I've a Laravel 4 join  as given below:

```
return DB::table(Location::getTableName() . ' as l')->where('l.company_id', $companyId)
        ->join(User::getTableName() . ' as u', 'u.location_id', '=', 'l.id')->whereIn('l.id', $locationsId)
        ->join(UserTimeline::getTableName() . ' as ut', 'ut.user_id', '=', 'u.id')
        ->join(Status::getTableName() . ' as s', 's.id', '=', 'ut.status_id')
        ->select(
            'l.name as location_name',
            'u.first_name as user_first_name',
            'u.last_name as user_last_name',
            'u.email as user_email',
            'ut.started_at as timeline_started_at',
            'ut.finished_at as timeline_finished_at',
            's.id as status_id',
            's.label as status_label'
        )
        ->orderBy('ut.id', 'asc')
        ->skip($from)
        ->limit($limit)
        ->get();
```

I've to detect the user's timezone and compute the difference from GMT as a number which might be +5 for Pakistan and +5.5 for India.
Now the problem with me is that I'm exporting the data of this join in a CSV file. I've to add hours as a number in 'timeline_started_at' and 'timeline_finished_at'. I've searched and found that 'DATEADD' method of SQL can add or subtract the hours.

The real problem is that I don't know that where in the above join I should use 'DATEADD' function in my Laravel join.

Can someone plz help me in this regard?????????

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DB::raw()`](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Connection.html#method_raw) to add sql functions to your query.

For example:

```
$test = DB::table('test')->where(DB::raw('DATE_ADD(created_at, 5)'), '<', $date)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like that:

```
return DB::table(Location::getTableName() . ' as l')->where('l.company_id', $companyId)
        ->join(User::getTableName() . ' as u', 'u.location_id', '=', 'l.id')->whereIn('l.id', $locationsId)
        ->join(UserTimeline::getTableName() . ' as ut', 'ut.user_id', '=', 'u.id')
        ->join(Status::getTableName() . ' as s', 's.id', '=', 'ut.status_id')
        ->select(
            'l.name as location_name',
            'u.first_name as user_first_name',
            'u.last_name as user_last_name',
            'u.email as user_email',
            'DATE_ADD(ut.started_at, INTERVAL '.$var.' HOUR) as timeline_started_at',
            'DATE_ADD(ut.finished_at, INTERVAL '.$var.' HOUR) as timeline_finished_at',
            's.id as status_id',
            's.label as status_label'
        )
        ->orderBy('ut.id', 'asc')
        ->skip($from)
        ->limit($limit)
        ->get();
```

Where `$var` represents the number of hours.

Comment: Giving error:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'DATE_ADD(ut.started_at,' in 'field list' (SQL: select `l`.`name` as `location_name`, `u`.`first_name` as `user_first_name`, `u`.`last_name` as `user_last_name`, `u`.`email` as `user_email`, `...................

Comment: Would you please try to add DB listener and dump the executed SQL?

Comment: I don't know how to do DB Listner, what else to do?

Comment: it's not dumping the query in listener, just giving errors. If I dump any other query, it works, but nor for this one.

Comment: Would you remove the $var and just type a static number DATE_ADD(ut.started_at, INTERVAL 5 HOUR)

Comment: Also what is the error return while dumping the query?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96892/discussion-between-mkj-and-mina-youssef).